# Cast function to 2 decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good morning I am trying to return the InvoiceTotal as a datatype decimal  with 2 digits to the right of the decimal. I have tried looking on W3 and other stack overflow pages and just cant find it. Would be awesome if someone could help me. Thanks

```
SELECT Invoices CAST ((InvoiceTotal) AS INT)
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near
> 'InvoiceTotal'.

Completion time: 2021-04-01T11:02:09.5404966-04:00

Here is some more pics to help.
[Pic of the table][image: 1]

Comment: I suggest you fix your schema now. Traditionally, attributes like DueDate should be defined as DATE not DATETIME. The MONEY datatype also has its share of quirks - better to use the appropriate NUMERIC datatype.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two decimal places, then use `decimal`/`numeric`, something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(InvoiceTotal AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
FROM Invoices;
```

Your query is also missing a `FROM` clause.